# How to launch android browser with a specific URL from pc?

Tags: android

I want to launch a browser in my android device with a specific url from PC, I don't know whether this is possible or not, so I'll be glad to know your ideas.

cheers,
Pooya

Comment: From the PC?  You'd basically need to have some kind of remote control software listening for commands on the phone side.

Comment: It is important for me to send launch command from my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your activity

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Oh, then a lot of more things need to be done. How do you want to send the command?

Comment: TRAP, ADB, I don't want to use it, actually I want to copy an apk into the device memory and launch its installation somehow (there may be no file manager so I decided to think about the browser)

Comment: Are you simply trying to install your app which is in your pc into the device using browser?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to make Debugging mode enabled, and it is important not to type the apk directory, it must be like windows autorun somehow.